# Set anonymous authentication into setJavaMailProperties in Spring

Tags: spring, email, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send an email with spring, but I received this exception

```
    Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: host, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mailhub, port: 246;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Caused for connection refused.

For this, I need to set the the connection as anonymous authentication

Right now, I have this

```
     @Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Value("mailhost")
    private String host;

    @Value("25")
    private Integer port;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailService() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setHost(host);
        javaMailSender.setPort(port);


        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(getMailProperties());

        return javaMailSender;
    }

    private Properties getMailProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "false");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

is there a way to implement anonymous authentication as a property?

Comment: It suppose you are setting mail.smtp.auth = false that should be enough